# Difference between Attachment and AttachmentData

Tags: c#, botframework

As per title, what is the difference between an Attachment and an AttachmentData?
I see the example at https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/CSharp/core-SendAttachment/SendAttachmentDialog.cs and it is not clear when we should use the first or the second.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `AttachmentData` class is basically the model that is sent when you use the Connector API to upload attachments to the channel.

In the [readme](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/core-SendAttachment) of that sample, you will find the different scenarios related to attachments.

Unless you are generating an image dynamically based on user input you might not need to go that route. If you already have an URL for the image, you can just use it.

More information also on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference#objects